# loading multiple reports in single cystal report viewer

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

i am passing a parameter called "CustomerId" to the crystal Report ('.rpt') file, based on the parameter its generating the report. when i load this report ('.rpt') to crystal report viewer its working fine...

But i have Different "CustomerId". i need to generate the report based on the parameter and load them into a single report viewer. i.e instead of viewing them single by single, i want to view them all into single report viewer as page wise.

can any one tell me how to solve this please....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your CustomerID parameter to accept multiple values. Also create a group by Customer and set start new page after for the last section in the group

Answer (score 1):

Create a report viewer for Each report. then report viewers add tab page on tab control.

[image: screenshot]

```
        private void FormCrystalRepotViewer_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReportDocument crReport = crArrReport[0];
        crystalReportViewer.ReportSource = crReport;
        crystalReportViewer.Zoom(100);
        crystalReportViewer.PrintMode = CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.PrintMode.PrintToPrinter;
        tcTabControl.TabPages[0].Text = arrRaporlar.Get(0).sReportName;

        for (int i = 1; i < crArrReport.Count; i++)
        {
            crReport = crArrReport[i];
            CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer crview = new CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer();

            crview.ReportSource = crReport;
            crview.Zoom(100);
            crview.PrintMode = crystalReportViewer.PrintMode;
            crview.ActiveViewIndex = -1;
            crview.BorderStyle = crystalReportViewer.BorderStyle;
            crview.Cursor = crystalReportViewer.Cursor;
            crview.Dock = crystalReportViewer.Dock;
            crview.Location = crystalReportViewer.Location;
            crview.Size = crystalReportViewer.Size;
            crview.TabIndex = 0;
            crview.ToolPanelView = crystalReportViewer.ToolPanelView;
            crview.ShowParameterPanelButton = crystalReportViewer.ShowParameterPanelButton;
            crview.ShowLogo = crystalReportViewer.ShowLogo;

            crview.ReportRefresh += new CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.RefreshEventHandler(this.crystalReportViewer_ReportRefresh);

            TabPage page = new TabPage(arrRaporlar.Get(i).sReportName);
            tcTabControl.TabPages.Add(page);
            page.Controls.Add(crview);
            page.AutoScroll = true;
        }
    }
        private void crystalReportViewer_ReportRefresh(object source, CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.ViewerEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        ParametreleriKontrolEt();
        crystalReportViewer.ReportSource = crArrReport[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < crArrReport.Count; i++)
        {
            CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer crview = new CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer();
            crview = tcTabControl.TabPages[i].Controls[0] as CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer;
            crview.ReportSource = crArrReport[i];
        }
    }
```